# Windows - Freeze on Save As Dialog Box

Tags: windows-10, freeze, save-as

I've come across an odd issue that I'm not sure has been around for a while or just something I've happened to come across, I've done some searching around already but can't see anything that really matches the issue.

Essentially - Windows 10 machines (various builds) when trying to "Save As" a file and you browse to the "root" of a server, for example \\FILES and you don't put a share name, the Save As dialog box freezes for a good 20 seconds.

If you browse to \\FILES\ShareName, it loads instantly as expected. I've managed to get this to happen on every Office app and Notepad/WordPad. But it doesn't seem to happen on any server build that I've tested with, only on Windows 10.

I've disabled Anti-Virus completely to rule this out and done the usual SFC checks etc. but with it happening on different machines and on completely different networks it's got me scratching my head.

Not a massive problem really in reality as I can tell the user just to go direct to the share they need but curious if anyone else has seen/had the issue?

Comment: Is the slow file location one that Windows 10 security prevents access to?  That would explain the delay.

Comment: I can't see any security issues when I've tried. I get the same symptoms when I access it this way as an admin also.

Comment: Make sure the User’s permissions are correct. A user using Admin to correct a user share error will always get a permission error.